# How to create a slide in tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I'm having problem figuring out how to code the support tab (on the right) of this page - http://test88.fccbet.com/. It currently slides out on click.

This is where I got the the current tab slide out effect: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

What I want is that both the main tab and side tab will appear when the page loads (refer to IMAGE1). But when the side tab image is clicked, the main image will hide itself leaving only the tab image (refer to IMAGE2).

(IMAGE1)This is how it currently looks like when the page loads:
echosantos dot com/tabslideout/tab-current-outcome.jpg

(IMAGE2)This is how I want it to look like when the page loads (basically I don't want to click the side tab first to see the rest of the tab) :
echosantos dot com/tabslideout/tab-desired-outcome.jpg

This is my first Stackoverflow question, I hope I gave you enough details for your answer. Thanks in advance for the help!

Cheers!

---

html:

```
<div id="bannerLeft">
<div class="slide-out-div no-phone no-phone-landscape" style="background-image:url(images/support-tab.png); "><br />
    <a href="javascript:supportPop('https://messenger.providesupport.com/messenger/043ddykhqw98l0mslsguhu8w79.html');" id="range-logo">Fccbet</a>
    <a class="handle" href="#"></a><div id="close-bottom"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/close-chat.jpg")"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.slide-out-div {
    width: 125px; 
    height:392px;
    background: url(../images/support-tab.png); }


#range-logo {
background-image:url(../images/support-tab.png);
display:block;
text-indent:-9999px;
width: 125px; 
height:396px;}
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
        tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
        pathToTabImage: '@routes.Assets.at("images/support-tab-side.png")',          //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)
        imageHeight: '284px',                               //height of tab image
        imageWidth: '43px',                               //width of tab image    
        tabLocation: 'right',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
        speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
        action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
        topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
        fixedPosition: true                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#close-bottom").click(function(){
    $("#bannerLeft").remove();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please show us your code that you have tried to achieve this functionality?

Comment: you can edit your own question by clicking on the edit button at left bottom of the question. And place your code in the question instead in comments.

Comment: no problem, i added the html, css and js codes related to the sliding tab..thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify your statement "*What I want is that both the main image and tab image will appear when the page loads. Then when the tab image is clicked, the main image will hide itself leaving only the tab image.*"

Comment: i edited it plus added some images, thanks for being patient, Joker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this line `$('.slide-out-div > .handle').click();` to achieve the target that you want. As you defined the click event on your handler tab so need to enforce a click on page load. Just add the following line in your `JQuery` code and place it after `$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({...});`

**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/1Lpdykhx/)**

```
$(function () { 

    $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
        tabHandle: '.handle', //class of the element that will become your tab
        pathToTabImage: 'http://wpaoli.building58.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
        imageHeight: '122px', //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
        imageWidth: '40px', //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
        tabLocation: 'left', //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
        speed: 300, //speed of animation
        action: 'click', //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
        topPos: '200px', //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
        leftPos: '20px', //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
        fixedPosition: false //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
    });


    $('.slide-out-div > .handle').click();    // Add this line and that's it

});
```

---

**JSFiddle Snippet**

Click on the below `Run code snippet` button to test it here.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.tabSlideOut = function(callerSettings) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      tabHandle: '.handle',
      speed: 300,
      action: 'click',
      tabLocation: 'left',
      topPos: '50px',
      leftPos: '20px',
      fixedPosition: false,
      positioning: 'absolute',
      pathToTabImage: null,
      imageHeight: null,
      imageWidth: null,
      onLoadSlideOut: false
    }, callerSettings || {});

    settings.tabHandle = $(settings.tabHandle);
    var obj = this;
    if (settings.fixedPosition === true) {
      settings.positioning = 'fixed';
    } else {
      settings.positioning = 'absolute';
    }

    //ie6 doesn't do well with the fixed option
    if (document.all && !window.opera && !window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      settings.positioning = 'absolute';
    }



    //set initial tabHandle css

    if (settings.pathToTabImage != null) {
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'background': 'url(' + settings.pathToTabImage + ') no-repeat',
        'width': settings.imageWidth,
        'height': settings.imageHeight
      });
    }

    settings.tabHandle.css({
      'display': 'block',
      'textIndent': '-99999px',
      'outline': 'none',
      'position': 'absolute'
    });

    obj.css({
      'line-height': '1',
      'position': settings.positioning
    });


    var properties = {
      containerWidth: parseInt(obj.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
      containerHeight: parseInt(obj.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px',
      tabWidth: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
      tabHeight: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px'
    };

    //set calculated css
    if (settings.tabLocation === 'top' || settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
      obj.css({
        'left': settings.leftPos
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'right': 0
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
      obj.css({
        'top': '-' + properties.containerHeight
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'bottom': '-' + properties.tabHeight
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
      obj.css({
        'bottom': '-' + properties.containerHeight,
        'position': 'fixed'
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'top': '-' + properties.tabHeight
      });

    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'left' || settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
      obj.css({
        'height': properties.containerHeight,
        'top': settings.topPos
      });

      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'top': 0
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
      obj.css({
        'left': '-' + properties.containerWidth
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'right': '-' + properties.tabWidth
      });
    }

    if (settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
      obj.css({
        'right': '-' + properties.containerWidth
      });
      settings.tabHandle.css({
        'left': '-' + properties.tabWidth
      });

      $('html').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
    }

    //functions for animation events

    settings.tabHandle.click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    var slideIn = function() {

      if (settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
        obj.animate({
          top: '-' + properties.containerHeight
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
        obj.animate({
          left: '-' + properties.containerWidth
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
        obj.animate({
          right: '-' + properties.containerWidth
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
        obj.animate({
          bottom: '-' + properties.containerHeight
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideIn).removeClass('open');
      }

    };

    var slideOut = function() {

      if (settings.tabLocation == 'top') {
        obj.animate({
          top: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'left') {
        obj.animate({
          left: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'right') {
        obj.animate({
          right: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'bottom') {
        obj.animate({
          bottom: '-3px'
        }, settings.speed, settings.onSlideOut).addClass('open');
      }

      settings.onSlideOut
    };

    var clickScreenToClose = function() {
      obj.click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });

      $(document).click(function() {
        slideIn();
      });
    };

    var clickAction = function() {
      settings.tabHandle.click(function(event) {
        if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
          slideIn();
        } else {
          slideOut();
        }
      });

      clickScreenToClose();
    };

    var hoverAction = function() {
      obj.hover(

        function() {
          slideOut();
        },

        function() {
          slideIn();
        });

      settings.tabHandle.click(function(event) {
        if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
          slideIn();
        }
      });
      clickScreenToClose();

    };

    var slideOutOnLoad = function() {
      slideIn();
      setTimeout(slideOut, 500);
    };

    //choose which type of action to bind
    if (settings.action === 'click') {
      clickAction();
    }

    if (settings.action === 'hover') {
      hoverAction();
    }

    if (settings.onLoadSlideOut) {
      slideOutOnLoad();
    };

  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {

  $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle', //class of the element that will become your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'http://wpaoli.building58.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
    imageHeight: '122px', //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
    imageWidth: '40px', //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
    tabLocation: 'left', //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300, //speed of animation
    action: 'click', //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '50px', //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
    leftPos: '20px', //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
    fixedPosition: false //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
  });

  $('.slide-out-div > .handle').click();

});
```

```css
.slide-out-div {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #29216d;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-out-div"> <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users.html">Content</a>

  <h3>Contact me</h3>

  <p>Thanks for checking out my jQuery plugin, I hope you find this useful.</p>
  <p>This can be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i've been cracking my brains with this problem and with just one line, it's fixed. 

you just made my day joker! thanks man!

Comment: No prob Joker, I marked this up as a correct answer. I have a follow-up question.

Right now the main tab hides if you click to any part of the webpage. What js should I add so it will only hide if I click the side tab?

Comment: If you have a new problem, then ask a new question for it :)